# Expresso Store, set tax rate at beginning of shopping

Tags: expresso-store

I am working on a project where the client would like the customer to select a region before adding to cart. The region has a tax_rate associated with it but is NOT dependant in IP or where the customer is located. Once of the selections is Dealer which offers a discount. How can I complete this. Please note, this is to be selected before anything else happens.

Comment: Can you edit your post to ask a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that this might work is if the user was logged in and has their profile filled out. They would need to have the Country/State/Zip filled out.

Store creates a new session tied to a Cart ID when you add a product to the cart which loads any existing shipping/billing information, clearing the cart kills that session clearing any billing/shipping info.

Your best bet would be to have the user add the first item to the cart and after they have done that you can use the `{exp:store:checkout}` tag pair to collect their Country/State/Zip (which ever you are using to set the tax rates) so that you can calculate the tax rate.